# Interrupts in x86 using assembly NASM

Tags: assembly, x86

I am a newbie to assembly language and currently working with interrupts in x86 architecture. Following is the code

```
BITS 16
start:
mov ax, 07C0h
add ax, 288
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096
mov ax, 07C0h
mov ds, ax

mov si, text
lodsb          ;Load a bit to al
mov ah, 09h    ;Write charecter and attribute at cursor position
mov cx, 03h    ;No.of times to write the charecter
mov bh, 00h
mov bl, 02h
int 10h

text db 'Hello',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H,  the code should display the character 'H' three times on the screen. But this is not happening. I would like to know what the error is.
I am using `NASM` in `Linux`

Comment: I am a bit confused.  Are you writing a boot loader?  How do you execute this code?

Comment: Works here (if booted in qemu).

Comment: @jester I booted it in qemu in a Linux VM hosted in Google Cloud, it didn't work for me

Comment: Well, you don't have an ending but otherwise the code looks sane from a glance. Try adding a `jmp $` after the `int 10h`.

Comment: @fuz yeah, I am writing a boot loader. I generated a virtual floppy using NASM and booted in qemu

Comment: @jester yeah it worked now. But may I know how jmp $ would effect it

Comment: It gives something sensible for the cpu to do as otherwise it would try to execute your text as code and then whatever else is in memory after that (if it hasn't crashed or jumped away by then).